# MySQL Trigger with REPLACE INTO TABLE?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

Is it possible to apply a trigger after a `REPLACE INTO TABLE` command? I figured it would be the same as after an `update` even but it doesn't seem so.

I have a `.csv` file that is downloaded once a day with the data then inserted into my Database as follows:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'mycsv.csv'
replace INTO TABLE mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Is it possible to apply a trigger on this?

My trigger which is set to execute `after update`:

```
BEGIN
IF !(NEW.`Trend Price` <=> OLD.`Trend Price`) THEN
INSERT INTO trend_prices values (old.idProduct, old.`Trend Price`, NEW.`Trend Price`, NOW());
END IF;
END
```

Comment: REPLACE = DELETE old + INSERT new. No UPDATE during the process.

Comment: I see. So I would need to modify how I insert the data? As replace wouldn't allow me to access the old data with a trigger?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the update trigger it uses insert and delete (when needed).

> 1. BEFORE INSERT;
> 2. BEFORE DELETE (if a row is being replaced);
> 3. AFTER DELETE (if a row is being replaced);
> 4. AFTER INSERT.

Source: https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2015/09/25/mariadbmysql-on-replace-triggers/

Comment: @Akina I have just tested triggers on my MacOS MySQL 5.7: If there is no record to replace, it fires (1) before insert, (2) after insert. If there is a record to replace it fires (1) before insert, (2) before delete, (3) after delete, (4) after insert — as mentioned above. Nothing to fix in my question.

Comment: Tested. Really... sorry. Thank you, now I know a little less wrong.